# SQL Server 2008 Restored Database allows differential backup when no full exists

Tags: sql-server, sql

I restored a backup file (it's used as a template for new databases) as a new database. Normally as part of this process, I take a full backup after the restore, but this time I was called away on another issue before I could do that and in the meantime, my regularly scheduled differential backup job ran. It successfully took a differential backup of this database without throwing any errors. Conversely, the log backup job failed correctly reporting there was no full backup available.

I have read in multiple places that you cannot take either a differential or a log backup without a full, so why is this particular database allowing a diff? Has anyone else ever encountered this behavior?

Answer (score 5):

It may seem counter-intuitive, but it's counting the full you restored it from as the last full backup.

This is a really good diagram to show what I'm talking about.

[image]

I got that image from [this article on restore chains and not breaking them](http://sqlmag.com/blog/breaking-backup-chain-redux-or-eating-crow), and the rest of the article is also really good.  (In short:  Copy only is your friend.)

Comment: You'll even see evidence of the restored database's backup status in the backup* take in msdb; the information is imported from the backup header on restore.